# Freemarker Cache Not Switching Off

Tags: freemarker

I have this in the web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>freemarker</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param><param-name>template_update_delay</param-name>
  <!-- ATTENTION, 0 is for development only! Use higher value otherwise. -->
  <param-value>0</param-value></init-param>
```

However, I have positively concluded that stale .ftl files are being delivered to the web browser.

I am not using any sort of 'Spring' or similar.

Using Freemarker 2.3.23.

Is there a more appropriate way to have Freemarker switch off its cache during development?

Comment: That should work... One thing I can think of is that the templates are loaded from a source that hides the changes due to its own caching. Where do you load the templates from (like what's your `TemplatePath` init-param)?

Comment: Hang on -- maybe not. It appears I had a rogue TemplatePath pointing off to a spot in left-field.